# Update a dict with part of another dict

Tags: python

I often find myself using this construct:

```
dict1['key1'] = dict2['key1']
dict1['key2'] = dict2['key2']
dict1['key3'] = dict2['key3']
```

Kind of updating `dict1` with a subset of `dict2`.

I think there is no a built method for doing the same thing in form

```
dict1.update_partial(dict2, ('key1', 'key2', 'key3'))
```

What approach you usually take? Have you made you own function for that? How it looks like?

Comments?

---

I have submitted an [idea](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2012-April/014728.html) to python-ideas:

Sometimes you want a dict which is subset of another dict. It would nice if
dict.items accepted an optional list of keys to return. If no keys are
given - use default behavior - get all items.

```
class NewDict(dict):

    def items(self, keys=()):
        """Another version of dict.items() which accepts specific keys to use."""
        for key in keys or self.keys():
            yield key, self[key]


a = NewDict({
    1: 'one',
    2: 'two',
    3: 'three',
    4: 'four',
    5: 'five'
})

print(dict(a.items()))
print(dict(a.items((1, 3, 5))))

vic@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ python test.py 
{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five'}
{1: 'one', 3: 'three', 5: 'five'}
```

So to update a dict with a part of another dict, you would use:

```
dict1.update(dict2.items(['key1', 'key2', 'key3']))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no built-in function I know of, but this would be a simple 2-liner:

```
for key in ('key1', 'key2', 'key3'):
    dict1[key] = dict2[key]  # assign dictionary items
```

Comment: I learned nothing new - there is really no any shortcut... I like this answer - it's more explicit. And i think it's faster than aquavitae's answer, as it doesn't create any intermediary list or generator.

Answer (score 12):

You could do it like this:

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
dict1.update((k, dict2[k]) for k in keys)
```

Comment: I think that it should be dict1.update({k : dict2[k] for k in keys}) (you update with a dict, not with a list)

Comment: @GuyAdini In 2.7, yours works as well. But in older versions, this didn't exist yet. aquavitae is absolutely correct.

Comment: Unless you need support for Python 2.3 you might as well just use a generator comprehension instead of a list comprehension. `dict1.update((k, dict2[k]) for k in keys)`

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that all keys of dict1 which are also in dict2 should be updated then probaly the most explicit way is to filter dict2 and update dict1 using the filtered dict1:

```
dict1.update(
    {k: v for k, v in dict2.items() if k in dict1})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1.update([(key, dict2[key]) for key in dict2.keys()])
```

Comment: Please explain what this does, and use four spaces of indentation so that your code is properly formatted.